# Using APK Splits for Release but not Debug build type

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've successfully implemented [APK Splits](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits) so that separate APKs are generated for different ABIs.

However, for efficiency (and since I have no need for non-armeabi-v7a APKs in Debug), I would like to limit Debug builds to only generate armeabi-v7a APKs.

How can this be done?

One idea is with this:

```
abi {
    enable true
    reset()
    include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
    universalApk false
}
```

Maybe there is some way to set `enable` based on the Build type?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can try a variation on @Geralt_Encore's answer, which avoids the separate `gradlew` command. In my case, I only cared to use APK splitting to reduce the released APK file size, and I wanted to do this entirely within Android Studio.

```
splits {
    abi {
      enable gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.contains("Release") }
      reset()
      include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
      universalApk false
    }
}
```

From what I've seen, the Build | Generate Signed APK menu item in Android Studio generates the APK using the `assembleRelease` Gradle target.

Comment: This works great, even when using flavors with multiple dimensions.

Comment: I've visited this issue probably 6 times now over the last year. You have just solved my ridiculous problem. Thank you forever.

Comment: Partial string match makes it a little cleaner `taskNames.any { it.contains("assembleRelease") }`

Comment: +1 for mentioning the dynamic check `gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":app:assembleRelease")`. This allowed me to include another app level check.

Answer (score 15):

You can set `enable` based on command line argument. I have solved kinda similar problem when I wanted to use splits only for the release version, but not for regular debug builds.

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable project.hasProperty('splitApks')
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
    }
}
```

And then `./gradlew -PsplitApks assembleProdRelease` (prod is a flavor in my case).

Comment: your answer is more offtopic, we're talking about building from Android Studio and not from command line, sh, bat, cmd, terminal and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this party, but having a problem with different flavors and tasks names, I've come with this:

```
ext.isRelease = { array ->
    array.each { name ->
        if (name.contains("Debug")) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

android {

...

    splits {
        abi {
            enable isRelease(gradle.startParameter.taskNames)
            reset()
            include "x86_64", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"
            universalApk false
        }
    }

}
```

It's just a small update to Jeff P's answer but works well with different flavors and build configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Update for [@Jeff P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1614687/jeff-p)'s answer to make it more flexible based on app name and to support Android App Bundle (.aab) format

```
splits {
    abi {
      enable gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.contains("Release") }
      reset()
      include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
      universalApk false
    }
}
```