# Android studio(2.2.0 and 2.2.1) sends wrong ABI split to device

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using ABI splits in my app

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

If i use a x86_64 emulator then switch to device (armeabi-v7a) (and also others), android studio sends app-x86_64-debug.apk to device

```
09/27 17:17:49: Launching app
$ adb push SampleFolder\app\build\outputs\apk\app-x86_64-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/sample.package
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/sample.package"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/sample.package
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
```

Edit : **The way of how i'm getting this issue**

- I closed the x86_64 emulator
- Connected real test device
- Followed Run - Edit Configurations - Target (Open Select Deployment Target Dialog)
- Chosed the connected test device

**Android Studio 2.2.1**

After releasing the 2.2.1, i had played a bit split distributions then everything was looking good. Unfortunately same problem happened to me again. To be make sure clearly, i created new android project and imported realm database (has native libraries) and then,

added split section to gradle

```
 splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'
    }
}
```

created application class

```
public class SampleApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        initRealm();
    }

    private void initRealm(){
        Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
        RealmConfiguration.Builder builder = new RealmConfiguration.Builder();
        builder.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded();
        RealmConfiguration configuration = builder.build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
    }
}
```

selected my device

[image]

**app worked, so studio sent appropriate apk(app-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk) to device**

```
$ adb push /home/blackkara/projects/Sample/app/build/outputs/apk/app-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.blackkara.sample
```

After all, i changed the code

```
public class SampleApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        initRealm();

        // The added code
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    private void initRealm(){
        Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
        RealmConfiguration.Builder builder = new RealmConfiguration.Builder();
        builder.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded();
        RealmConfiguration configuration = builder.build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
    }
}
```

**then ran app again, but this time studio sent wrong apk(app-armeabi-debug.apk) to device**

```
 $ adb push /home/blackkara/projects/Sample/app/build/outputs/apk/app-armeabi-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.blackkara.sample
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the bottom code-formatted snippet is showing output from Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, i just changed package name to sample.package

Comment: How are you switching to the device? Are you just choosing the device when running the app from the IDE?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare something wrong with me ?

Comment: I was asking for clarification. I am not in position to try to reproduce this experiment right now, sorry.

Comment: The same thing is driving me nuts too. Could you find a solution by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately, cant find a solution for studio's weird behavior.  Just remove the whole split section in gradle and use universal apk instead of distributions. Before publishing the new version of your app,  add split section and move distributions to your test devices manually.

Comment: Here's how you can do it http://stackoverflow.com/a/39470840/2444099. Unless you are the author of NDK code, that should suffice.

Comment: @EugenPechanec it just sets `enable` property based on command line. The problem is here, Android Studio(2.2) does not send appropriate apk when `enable` is true. Before 2.2 version, studio was able to send appropriate apk to each connected real test devices. But now it sends only app-x86_64-debug.apk

Comment: Understood, i was reacting to your previous comment. Disable splits for android studio and enable it via a parameter when running final build from command line.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thanks, it's a good trick for my workaround.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Issue 215493](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215493&can=1&q=INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) a fix has been released in Android Studio 2.2.1.